# get text from all edittexts in a layout - android programming

Tags: java, android

I want the "loadingfiletext" (public String-array) to be the value of the EditTexts in the editts linear layout. If you need more info just ask for it. Here is my code:

```
for ( int ll=0; ll < 5 * szer; ll++ )
                {
                    EditText mb = ( (EditText)editts.getChildAt(ll + 1) );


                    loadingfiletext[ll] = String.valueOf(mb.getText());
                }
```

Comment: @VivekMishra I have an unknown X amount of Edit Texts in a Linear Layout and I want to put all their texts/values to a String array.

Comment: @VivekMishra Sorry I know the number of the edit texts its 5* szer (int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each of your `EditText` to a `List<EditText>`, and then iterate trough that list like

```
List<EditText> mList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(EditText mEditText : mList){
   mEditText.getText().toString();
}
```